# MongoDB Query: Find documents which match a given value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have Mongo DB collection which contains items like below:

```json
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("123123123123123123"), 
    "title" : "Item-001", 
    "tags" : [
        "red"
    ], 
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("234234234234234"), 
    "title" : "Item-002", 
    "tags" : [
        "red,yellow"
    ], 
}
```

**Objective:**
I want to find items which has `red` tag. So for this example, I want to get both Item-001 and Item-002.

**What I have tried**
I have tried with the below query, but it returns just `Item-001`. My objective is to get `Item-002` also as it contains red tag. How can I structure my query so that I can get both the documents?

```js
db.getCollection("items").find({
    "tags": { '$in': [ 'red'] },
})
```

Comment: Do you really have `"tags" : ["red,yellow"]`?... or is it `"tags" : ["red", "yellow"]`?

Comment: You could just use `db.getCollection("items").find({"tags": "red"})`.

Comment: Sorry, it is infact `"tags" : ["red,yellow"]`. Is there any way we can query this?

Comment: Is that what you want?  Do you want to change it?

Comment: That is what I have in my db. Can I query it without changing?

Comment: You could use [`db.getCollection("items").find({"tags": {"$regex": "\\bred\\b"}})`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cFlh6qO2O4U).  You may or may not need the double ``\\`` ... a single ``\`` may do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First solution

You can do it with `find()` query and `$regex` operator:

```js
db.collection.find({
 "tags": {
   "$regex": "red"
 }
})
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zPLU_owk7vJ)

---

### Second solution

You can do it with Aggregation framework:

- `$match` with `$expr` - to filter documents based on custom filter
- `$filter` with `$regexMatch` - to filter **tags** array in each document and see if it has at least one item that contains "**red**".
- `$size` - to get the size of the above filtered array.
- `$gt` - to check if filtered array have at least one element.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$gt": [
          {
            "$size": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$tags",
                "cond": {
                  "$regexMatch": {
                    "input": "$$this",
                    "regex": "red"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DNNf7yQZRfD)

Answer (score 1):

Your tags field is an array, but the items are joined by comma delimiter. This looks like a mistake. You should change it if possible.

If not possible, here's a solution by splitting the string to a list and then matching.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "tagList": {
        $split: [
          {"$arrayElemAt": ["$tags", 0]}, ","
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "tagList": "red"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/98dQyOG5kad)

Comment: thanks for the help! Yes it looks like a mistake. Since the data was uploaded from a csv file, I guess due to some mistake in parsing the delimiters, the data got populated in such a way. But still it was nice to know how this scenario could be handled